# Simple string modification program in c

Tags: c, string

I need help with a simple string exercise in C.

I have received this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    printf("How are you?\n");
    printf("I\'m OK, and you?\n"
           "1, 2, 3, testing ...\n"
           "\t  Looks OK :-)\n"
           "   Bye bye!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

and I need to modify this other code to print out the same result, using as few characters as possible.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_printf(char*p){
    char s[strlen(p)+1], *q=s;
    strcpy(s,p);

/***TO BE DONE START ***/ 


/*** TO BE DONE END ***/

}

int main(){
     my_printf("hello world!");
     my_printf("How are you?");
     my_printf("i\'m OK, and you?");
     my_printf("1, 2, 3, testing ...");
     my_printf("\t  looks OK :-)");
     my_printf("   bye bye!");
     exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  How can you print the same text with less characters?

Comment: As few characters in the string literals, or in the source code as a whole?  Using `p()` instead of `my_printf()` will eliminate characters from the code as a whole.  Using `puts()` avoids a custom `my_printf()` function.  Using `"…'…"` instead of `"…\'…"` saves a character per single quote — you don't need to escape single quotes in double-quoted strings.

Comment: What do you want `my_printf` function to do? Print its parameter followed with a new line? Gather everything in a static buffer? Or...

Comment: I only need to modify the part beetween the comments /***TO BE DONE START***/ and /***TO BE DONE END***/. The myprintf function needs to modify the string given by imput changing the first charachter of the string if it is in lower case. This has to be done also in the case that the string starts with spaces or \t, with a final result that needs to be the same of the first code.

Comment: I should use as few charachers as possible to write the code.

Comment: read about [`puts`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/puts) which add a newline char at the end of the string

Comment: You should edit the updated requirement into the question, @MattiaOrsi.  Your overall description is misleading or even incorrect — you say "print out the same result" but your comment says "modify the string given by input changing the first character of the string if it is in lower case".  That's a very different problem.

Comment: "*I only need to modify the part between the comments /***TO BE DONE START***/ and /***TO BE DONE END***/.*" - Why do you say "modify"? There is no code between these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the first non-whitespace character to uppercase, and add a final newline...

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_printf(char *p) {
    //print optional initial whitespace as is
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*p)) putchar(*p++);
    //convert 1st char to uppercase
    putchar(toupper((unsigned char)*p++));
    //print the rest with a newline
    puts(p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try

Comment: May I ask why you cast `*p` to `unsigned char`?

Comment: I cast because `isspace("café"[3])` invokes UB if it's negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_printf (char *p) {
    char s[strlen(p)+1], *q = s;
    strcpy(s,p);

    while (isspace(*q)) q++;

    if ( *q >= 'a' && *q <= 'z' ) 
    {
        *q -= ' ';
    }

    puts(s);
}
```